# How show animation with clipboard in android compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I use Clipboard:

```
val clipboardManager: ClipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
Icon(
     imageVector =  ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_copy_track_number),
     contentDescription = "Copy",
     modifier = Modifier
               .padding(start = 4.dp)
               .size(16.dp)
               .clickable {        
                           clipboardManager.setText(AnnotatedString(trackNumber))
                           }
    )
```

And I had a question: how to make a temporary animation that changes color for the duration of a user's click (in this case, briefly replace it with another icon), for example, for 2 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `InteractionSource` object. You can find an example over [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/handling-interactions#icon-button-example).

Instead of the AnimatedVisibility you'll need an infinite animation for your icon's colour:

```
@Composable
private fun ColourAnimatedButton(interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")

    val idleColor = Color.Blue
    val animatedColor by infiniteTransition.animateColor(
        initialValue = Color.Blue, targetValue = Color.Red, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = keyframes {
                durationMillis = 1000 // the speed at which colours will change
            }, repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ), label = ""
    )

    Icon(imageVector =  ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_copy_track_number),
         contentDescription = "Copy", modifier = Modifier
           .padding(start = 4.dp)
           .size(16.dp).clickable(interactionSource, LocalIndication.current) {             
                 clipboardManager.setText(AnnotatedString(trackNumber))
            },
            tint = if (isPressed) animatedColor else idleColor
        )
    }
```

EDIT (onClick one-off animation)
(remove the `isPressed`, `infiniteTransition`, `idleColor`, and `animatedColor` and add this instead:

```
val color = remember { Animatable(Color.Black) }
```

Click listener changes to this:

```
.clickable(interactionSource, LocalIndication.current) {
     scope.launch {
         color.animateTo(Color.Blue, tween(500))
         color.animateTo(Color.Black, tween(500))
     }
 },
```

and finally set the colour like this: `tint = color.value`

Comment: OK, thank you.
I put it in the right place, but I don’t see the repainting animation.
What is speed for, can you please explain?

Comment: It is necessary to change the color from black to blue for a short time

Comment: The speed is how quickly it will go from one colour to another. Do you just want it to change the colour for as long as the user presses it, or do you want to animate between the 2 colours?

Comment: conditionally, so that one icon (black) changes to another (blue), literally for a second, so that the user can see this so-called "animation"

Comment: Check my edit. And some shameless promotion: I had a talk about animations at a few conferences; I think you may find my slides useful :)  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ZaqdgdkJhBUlWDyHieXMAoOaRqfA4jfE34hWwt21abs/present?slide=id.g13e021bb878_0_12

Comment: Thank you, what you need)
P.S. Regarding the performance - I'll look at the weekend (sorry that I didn't check yours earlier, my hands didn't reach)